# How to build a machine learning model using dataset with libsvm format

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka, libsvm

I have a dataset written on the `.libsvm` format, and i want to build a model of classification using Machine Learning algorithms.
I've tried the Weka environment version 3.6.12 but i get the following error:

`weka.core.convrters.LibSVMLoaderfailed to load 'train.ecml.libsvm.txt' 
Reason:
Unable to determine structure as libsvm:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:String index out of range: -1`

So, How to solve this problem or is there any other simple way to deal with this data file format ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Citing only the environment is not enough.  You should search the Internet for an example that fits your environment (Windows 10) and algorithm (SVM).  When you run into problems following the instructions or tutorial, check with the parent site's Q&A resources -- and *then* post here if you can't find help.

Comment: Thank you Mr @Prune i have a question on how to deal with the libsvm format to build an efficient machine Learning model ?

Comment: Then post the question -- but please follow the posting guidelines in the intro tour.

Comment: Please post the command that you tried in the command line, and the error that you received. Also post the screenshot of the GUI that you used when you loaded the dataset so we can help you. I loaded a libsvm dataset without any error in the Weka Explorer GUI.

Comment: @CaptainFogetti i edit my question. Could you help me!

Comment: @HaKiM's Are you sure that this is in libsvm format? Can you also post one or two lines of the data file?

Comment: @CaptainFogetti i solved the problem, thank you for helping me, i just used the weka.core.converters.SVMLightLoader and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load `.libsvm` data file format using the `weka.core.converters.SVMLightLoader`
Thank you.